# Alpha-Numeric Sorting

Tags: java, sorting

I am having a list of strings like

```
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-1511  
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-151  
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-152  
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-1513
```

When normal sorting is applied to these strings, they are sorted as

```
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-151  
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-1511  
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-1513
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-152
```

Instead of

```
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-151  
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-152
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-1511  
00785-LT-SUN(4)-SE-FD-1513
```

I have partially implemented the solution by going through following steps:

> 1. Separate all characters, numbers and special characters.

```
private static final Pattern VALID_PATTERN =   
               Pattern.compile ( "[0-9]+|[A-Z]+|[-()/.,:;]+|[\\s]+" );
```

> 2. Add each individual token of the original string to a list

```
private List<String> parse(String toParse) {
        List<String> chunks = new LinkedList<> ();
        Matcher matcher = VALID_PATTERN.matcher(toParse);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            chunks.add( matcher.group() );
        }
        return chunks;
    }
```

> 3.Each of these lists representing a string are added to a list

```
for (int i = 0 ;i < chunks.size () ;i++)
    listListString .add ( parse ( chunks.get ( i ) ) );
```

> 4.The actual Sorting applied on a particular column

```
public List<List<String>> Compare (List<List<String>> var_listArrayList ,
                                        int Col )
    {
        final int col_num = Col;
//this method can be overloaded to sort integers
            Collections.sort ( var_listArrayList,

                           new Comparator< List< String > > ( )
                           {

                               @Override
                               public
                               int compare ( List< String > a,
                                             List< String > b )
                               {

                                   return a.get ( col_num )
                                           .compareTo ( b.get ( col_num ) );
                               }
                           } );

        return var_listArrayList ;
    }
```

> The Actual Problem:
>   In spite of doing all of the the above mentioned steps, the result is still no as expected.

The possible solution is to go by the following steps:

```
static final Comparator< StringEncapsulator > ORDER_BY_COLS = new Comparator< StringEncapsulator >() {
    public int compare(StringEncapsulator a1, StringEncapsulator a2) {
        int i = ORDER_BY_COL1.compare(a1,a2);
        if(i == 0){
            i = ORDER_BY_COL2.compare(a1,a2);
            if(i == 0){
                i = ORDER_BY_COL3.compare(a1,a2);
                :
                :
                :
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
};  //the class here represents the encapsulated structure of the string
```

But the solution has a few difficulties.

- The strings may not always have same format which means that I would have to create a different type of class for each type of string i encounter.
- A recursive approach to the problem would be much easier to implement rather than hard-coding the entire `Comparator` function.

Comment: Side note on code quality: where is that `class` coming from that your ORDER_BY_COLS comparator is using?

Comment: One of the strings in your input has a `(1)` instead of a `(4)` - please verify the actual and expected output, because a simple string sort should put that with `(1)` as first regardless of the other numbers

Comment: Do you only want to sort the Strings according to their last number or what are the criteria?

Comment: What I mean is: you write `Comparator<class>" ... and that doesn't make any sense in my eyes.

Comment: @Jägermeister `class StringEncapsulator { String s1; String s2; String s3; : : @Override public String toString() { return "String [" + s1 + " | " + s2 + " | " + s3 + " ... ]"; } public Address(String s1, String s2, String s3, ...) { super(); this.s1 = s1; this.s2 = s2; this.s3 = s3; : : } }`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just sort your list with a Comparator that looks something like this:

```
new Comparator<String> ( )
{
  @Override
  public
  int compare (String a, String b)
  {
    String[] myAArray = a.split("-");
    Integer myAInt = Integer.parseInt(myAArray [myAArray.length - 1]);

    String[] myBArray = b.split("-");
    Integer myBInt = Integer.parseInt(myBArray [myBArray.length - 1]);

    return myAInt > myBInt ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current design is "procedural" - you wrote code to work a "fixed" (inflexible) data structure. Consider using a "real OO" design here.

The point is: yes, your data is coming in as "raw strings" with certain properties. But: that doesn't mean that you always have to treat your data as strings.

Instead, you could **model** a class that represents such data. That would also allow to separate different concerns: one class is responsible to parse the incoming string and turns them into specific objects; and then you can implement a reasonable equals() method within each such class.

That way you would make the various properties of your strings a "fully qualified" property of the class representing it; instead of doing all this implicit "there are 'columns' in the strings; that need to be handled this way/that way".

Comment: As i have already mentioned in the post; this is just a sample and the strings may not follow the same structure every time. The structure would be same only for sets of strings which are to be sorted. But each set may have a different structure which would lead to creation of new classes and their comparators every time  I encounter a different string pattern eg  MNP JT2 A 14001. What I need here is a generic solution

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea, not a full solution: if you're willing to look into (or are already using) external libraries, Apache Commons Collections provides a [ComparatorChain](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/collections4/comparators/ComparatorChain.html), which could help you with chaining together comparators for each of the chunks. This is of course assuming that you know the exact layout of your input string before the whole process starts.